# Does Apache Camel replace Apache commons pipeline

Tags: apache-commons, apache-camel, pipeline

I am implementing a parallelized data processing system that involves a bunch of conversions and filters of data as it moves through multiple stages. I recognize the [Apache Commons Pipeline](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/pipeline/) project as a good fit for this requirement, but Apache Camel seems to provide a superset of that functionality. Does Camel replace the Commons Pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Camels goal is more to be a mediator/routing engine in distributed systems and systems integration. That said, as you notice, it is very lightweight and could easily serve as an engine for parallellized execution of data flows. I don't think you should see camel as a replacement, rather an alternative.

Comment: Thanks @Petter. I have also struggled to find any real usage of the commons pipeline. Will share my observations on the component as this progresses.

Comment: One benefit of using camel for this is that it will be very easy to distribute pipeline execution to several nodes in a network or locally - if that is a benefit to your project.